# Android Collapsing Toolbar does not collapse

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following layout that has a collapsing toolbar with a LinearLayout inside -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".application_flow.group.GroupOverviewFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:stateListAnimator="@animator/show_toolbar">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
                app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:title="Lohamei Galipoly 38"
                app:titleEnabled="false"
                app:toolbarId="@id/group_tasks_toolbar">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.6">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/group_tasks_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/left_arrow_white"
                        app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        tools:text="Total group tasks: 8" />

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/group_tasks_tab_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/group_tasks_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

For some reason it does not collapse the entire content of the LinearLayout like it should and it is being left fixed in place.

This error seemed to start happening after I switched to work with the LinearLayout inside my CollapsingToolbarLayout

What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing an actual toolbar inside the collapsing toolbar.
try adding a toolbar after the linear layout's closing tag.
example:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:title="Toolbar title" />
```

and another thing I noticed, you AppBarLayout has `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` so check that as well.

Comment: It's already have a `Toolbar` after `LinearLayout`'s closing tag!!